# Using the ADBC driver to read or write to a database is crashing python

Tags: arrow-adbc

I am having issues with the adbc drivers in python. I can read/write from the database using sqlalchemy and/or connectorx - but not with any of the adbc drivers.

Trying to run any read/write with the adbc engine crashes the python process and jupyter kernel.

I am on Windows 11.

I don't expect this to be enough to fix the issue - but can someone point me in the direction of the logs I need to reference to troubleshoot the issue?

I tried looking at the jupyter logs, but the error was not described there beyond "kernel died".

It might be related to this: https://github.com/apache/arrow-adbc/issues/1531